# Como posicionar uma div lado a lado com JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou criando um sistema simples de chat onde tem uma função que abre a janela do usuário ao qual quer conversar estilo do face. O que gostaria de saber é como ao abrir o segundo usuário a janela ficar alinhada do lado da primeira janela e não acima que é o que esta acontecendo. Esse é o código no momento.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chat').die('click').live("click", function () {
        var chat = $(this).attr("rel");
        var URL = 'chat.php';
        var dataString = 'chat=' + chat;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("body").append("<div id='main" + chat + "'></div>")
                $("#main" + chat).html(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
<style>
#chatbox {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 4;
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  border: 1px solid #000;

}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<a  class="chat"  rel="8" href="#">user A </a>
<br/>
<a  class="chat"  rel="7" href="#">user b </a>
```

Comment: Jones, falta aqui bastante informação. Onde está o elemento `#chatbox` no HTML? Pode fazer um jsFiddle com um exemplo? as novas janelas de chat são `<div>` ou `<a>`?

Comment: Aqui fica uma ajuda para o jsFiddle que deve fazer: http://jsfiddle.net/684en/

Comment: Cuidado com o uso da `.live`, está deprecated, substituída pela `.on` ou `.delegate`.
http://api.jquery.com/live/
 Se irá construir um chat, recomendo olhar também sobre long polling, para evitar requisições desnecessárias.
http://imasters.com.br/artigo/23436/javascript/veja-como-o-long-polling-pode-te-ajudar-a-desenvolver-aplicacoes-em-tempo-real/

Comment: Seu título original fala de "JavaScript", mas seu código é jQuery, e talvez o problema seja no CSS/HTML (?) O guia [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) merece uma lida.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma ul e setar display como inline e position absolute e com jquery ir adicionando itens (janelas de chat que pode ser uma div) nessa lista.

```
$("#ul_id").append("<li><div id='chat_" + chat_id + "'></div></li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponha que você queira alinhar as janelas de chat a direita então você tem que atribuir também o valor do atributo right no CSS via JQuery. Atribua valores crescentes em quantidade de 205px pois a largura da sua "janela" é 200px;